MoleculePlot atom labels too large in version 14.1 in Linux
It appears that the internal scaling for MoleculePlot is off in the Linux version of Mathematica 14.1.
The following sample code is an illustration of my point:
$Version
MoleculePlot["CC(C)(C)c1ccc(CC(=O)NS(=O)(=O)c2nc(Cl)cs2)cc1"]

In Windows 11, the output is:

But in Fedora 40 (with all the latest drivers, etc.), the output is:

May I please request other Linux users to confirm that they are seeing something similar, before I report this as a bug to Wolfram Research?
Edit 1
In response to the test proposed by @Xylochoron, here is my output:

Edit 2
More information about the Linux installation:

Fedora 40 Workstation
Kernel version 6.9.12.200
GNOME 46.3.1
X11 (but the problem exists in Wayland too, and in any case, this cannot be the source of the problem)

The hardware and operating system are unlikely to be the problem since Mathematica Version 14.0 displays the molecule plots correctly on the same machine.

I mean it looks like a font problem of some kind.

In MoleculePlot the letters are not from a font. They are actually made with graphics, as one can inspect by looking at InputForm.

Oh those are S's that have been clipped off. Sorry. They looked like entirely new characters.

Please report this to technical support, I can try to debug at that point

@JasonB. thanks, will do.

We could try to debug this here in chat

Just a guess. I have a similar problem in 14.1 on Linux and filed as a bug report. Xyloc says below that he has no problems on Linux. Check which desktop/window managers you use. Is is possible that you use LXDE or LXQt and it works fine on Gnome or XFCE? On Linux we have different desktop/window managers, on Win it's all the same.

@AndreasLauschke In my bug report to Wolfram Research, I did mention that I am using Fedora 40, with kernel version 6.9.200.12, GNOME version 46.3.1. Maybe I should include the information in the original post as well.

@Shredderroy: My point was: discuss with Xyloc, because it's working him on Linux.

I work for Wolfram. I just checked on my Linux machine and it looked fine:

Yes you're right that these are actually graphics and not fonts. Maybe we can troubleshoot this a bit. I tried making a more simplified graphics example from the input form. Can you try running this on your machine?:
Graphics[{Style[{Line[{{2.5`, 0.`}, {2.8`, 0.1`}}]}], 
  Tooltip[{{RGBColor[0.433, 0.467, 0.467], 
     FilledCurve[{{{0, 2, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}}, {{{3.02`, 
         0.24`}, {3.02`, 0.38`}, {3.04`, 0.38`}, {3.04`, 0.32`}}}]}}, 
   2]}]

the output should look like this:

but we'll see how it looks for you, and whether that looks ok on your machine or not, maybe you can do some more experimenting to see where it does go wrong, or otherwise I can try giving you some more suggestions to try after you try this, thanks!

please see the original post. My output to your test seems to be correct.
